# AutoSuggestBox query selected textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I am using an AutoSuggestBox control to display some results, as such:

```
                <AutoSuggestBox Width="192"
                                PlaceholderText="Search"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        ...
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <Run Text="(" /><Run Text="{Binding Origin_Country[0]}" /><Run Text=")" />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
```

**SearchResults** (ItemsSource binding) is defined as such:

```
    private ObservableCollection<ShowModel> _searchResults = default(ObservableCollection<ShowModel>);
    public ObservableCollection<ShowModel> SearchResults { get { return _searchResults; } set { Set(ref _searchResults, value); } }
```

And **ShowModel** is a basic model with bindable properties.

The problem I'm having is when I'm clicking on one of the results, it is filling the textbox with the path of the model, as seen below:

Before selecting an entry:
[image]

After selecting an entry:
[image]

What I want is to define some sort of template for the textbox to bind to one of the model's properties so the model path is not displayed. Is this even possible?

Comment: Not a Windows 8 phones developer myself but can you tap into the SuggestionChosen event, cancel the selection there and set the content of the textbox manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `TextMemberPath` property to one of model's properties that you want to display.

```
TextMemberPath="someproperty"
```

Comment: Wow, easier than I expected. Thank you!